# Set limit to text length of column

Tags: peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I am fairly new to using BI Publisher (MS Word plugin) with PeopleSoft. I have a payment statement that I am adding some data elements to and I have noticed that with the Invoice Number field in some cases the number/test string is longer and it pushes the column next to it (Gross Amt) down to the row below it, as illustrated below.

The Invoice number is "Final set up testing 1099 2" and the Gross Amt is "1,000.00", however the length of the Invoice Nbr has pushed the Gross Amt to be below it.

**Example:**
[image]

**This is how I have the template (RTF file) setup as (both fields highlighted):**

[image]

Any ideas how I can either give the Invoice Nbr field a fixed width, or somehow prevent the Gross Amt from pushing down to the next line below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that behavior I am wondering whether the content area is a table.  Here is something to try... click on one of those fields and see if you get the "Table Tools" menu in the MSWord ribbon bar.  If you do then on the Layout tab select "View Gridlines".  That will help to see how the content area is built and how the elements are related.

If the fields are in a table then you can modify the table properties to better control the column and/or cell sizes.  Right-click on the values, select "Table Properties."  On the Table tab select Options then deselect "Automatically resize to fit contents."  Then on the Column tab and Cell tabs you can set column sizes.  The Cell, Options allows you to control text wrapping. You would probably want to set a column width for Invoice Nbr, then turn on text wrapping.

If those fields are the same column you may need to split them.  If it is not a table then you may need to make one or try some other formatting options in Word.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I selected each field and I do NOT see any change in what is displayed on the ribbon. I thought perhaps there was some kind of code I could add to the field(s) to either automatically resize or prevent the text from shifting below.

Comment: I have found somewhat of a workaround. I discovered that both of these fields were part of the same column, so I split them into two and now the long invoice number wraps the text into two line and leaves the gross amount where it should be positioned.